# How do you find out release, mailing list statistics information on open source projects

Tags: maven-2, statistics, richfaces, code-statistics

We are interested in finding out some statistics of various frameworks

1. Mailing list activity on say [richfaces](http://community.jboss.org/en/richfaces?view=discussions). Much similar to what is available on http://code.google.com (Low, Medium, High) + average number of emails per day | per month.
2. Number of releases made in a year including patch, minor, major releases. We did look at the maven repositories but that wasn't very useful either.

We did look at [ohloh](http://www.ohloh.net/p/11604), but didn't get the desired information. Any other ideas on where to get this information (any maven-2 plugins)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Mailing list activity on say richfaces. Much similar to what is available on http://code.google.com (Low, Medium, High) + average number of emails per day | per month.

You'll get these informations on [markmail](http://markmail.org/search/?q=list%3Aorg.apache.myfaces.users) (check also the other lists for [richfaces](http://markmail.org/search/?q=richfaces), e.g. the [svn-commits](http://markmail.org/search/?q=richfaces#query:richfaces%20list%3Aorg.jboss.lists.richfaces-svn-commits+page:1+state:facets)).

> Number of releases made in a year including patch, minor, major releases. We did look at the maven repositories but that wasn't very useful either.

I would use Jira's [Change Log](https://jira.jboss.org/browse/RF#selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.project:changelog-panel&allVersions=true) for that.

Comment: jira change log does provide summary of the recent milestone releases, but doesn't have the granularity of an year. I thought since the artifacts were published to the maven repository it might have some date indicating when it was released. But they seem to have a modified datae equivalent to when they were last synced.

Comment: average volume of email messages on markmail seems to be fine.